# LINQ query for DateTime ranges overlapping in collection items

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, logic

In the following case, the method *CanUnloadAll* checks if **there are no overlap in the unloading times**, considering all trucks.

The current scenario, should returns TRUE but it is returning FALSE.

What's wrong with the logic in the LINQ query?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class UnloadingTime
{
    public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime End { get; private set; }

    public UnloadingTime(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }
}

public static class UnloadingTrucks
{
    public static bool CanUnloadAll(IEnumerable<UnloadingTime> unloadingTimes)
    {
        return unloadingTimes.Any(
                TruckA => unloadingTimes.Any(
                    TruckB => TruckB != TruckA &&
                           !((
                               TruckA.Start.Date >= TruckB.End.Date || 
                               TruckB.Start.Date >= TruckA.End.Date
                            ))
                ));
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var format = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;

        UnloadingTime[] unloadingTimes = new UnloadingTime[] 
        {
            new UnloadingTime(DateTime.Parse("3/4/2019 19:00", format), DateTime.Parse("3/4/2019 20:30", format)),
            new UnloadingTime(DateTime.Parse("3/4/2019 22:10", format), DateTime.Parse("3/4/2019 22:30", format)),
            new UnloadingTime(DateTime.Parse("3/4/2019 22:40", format), DateTime.Parse("3/4/2019 23:00", format))
        };

        Console.WriteLine(UnloadingTrucks.CanUnloadAll(unloadingTimes));
    }
}
```

To make it easier, I am using .NET Fiddle.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mis663

Regards

Solution:

```cs
    public static bool CanUnloadAll(IEnumerable<UnloadingTime> unloadingTimes)
    {
        bool hasOverlap = unloadingTimes.Any(
                TruckA => unloadingTimes.Any(
                    TruckB => TruckB != TruckA &&
                           !((
                               TruckA.Start >= TruckB.End || 
                               TruckB.Start >= TruckA.End
                            ))
                ));
        
        return !hasOverlap;
    }
```

Comment: What does "conflict in the unloading times" mean?

Comment: If you mean there is no overlap between the times then it seems the `!((` should be `((` to me.

Comment: Yes. I mean overlap. I tested removing the `!` and returns true.  But when I changed a DateTime overlaping the times (the last one ex.: `new UnloadingTime(DateTime.Parse("3/4/2019 21:40", format), DateTime.Parse("3/4/2019 23:00", format)`), also returns true.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `DateTime.Date` property, which is the date component without the time part. You must use the `DateTime`:

```
bool flag = TruckA.Start >= TruckB.End || TruckB.Start >= TruckA.End
```

Comment: Exactly! It was not considering the time correctly.

In addition, I refactored the method to returns a logical complement.

Comment: Added solution on body. Thank you.